# How to work with styled components in my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, styled-components

I had trouble naming this question and it seems quite broad, so, forgive me oh moderators. I'm trying out [styled components](https://styled-components.com/) for the first time and trying to integrate it into my react app. I have the following so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Heading = styled.h1`
    background: red;
`;

class Heading extends React.Component {

    render () {

        return (
            <Heading>
                {this.props.title}
            </Heading>
        );
    }

}

export default Heading;
```

So, just a normal class, but then I import `styled components` up top, define the `const Heading`, where I specify that a `Heading` really is just a styled `h1`. But I get an error stating that `Heading` is a duplicate declaration since I also say `class Heading...`.

I'm obviously completely missing something here. All the examples online doesn't actually show how you also use this with React. I.e. where do I define my class, my constructor, set my state, etc.

Do I have to move the styled component into it's own file, i.e.:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Heading = styled.h1`
    background: red;
`;

export default Heading;
```

Then create a React component that will serve as a wrapper of sorts, e.g. 'HeadingWrapper':

```
import React from 'react';
import Heading from './Heading';

class HeadingWrapper extends React.Component {

    render () {

        return (
            <Heading>
                {this.props.title}
            </Heading>
        );
    }

}

export default HeadingWrapper;
```

A bit of clarity on this would greatly be appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

`` styled.h1`...` `` (for example) returns a React component that works just like `<h1>`. In other words, you use `<h1>` like this:

```html
<h1>h1's children</h1>
```

...so when you do `` const Heading = styled.h1`...`; ``, you'll use `<Heading>` the same way:

```html
<Heading>Heading's children</Heading>
```

If you want a component that behaves differently, e.g. one that uses the `title` prop instead of `children`, you'll need to define such a component, and it will need to have a different name than the Heading component you already defined.

For example:

```js
const styled = window.styled.default;

const Heading = styled.h1`
  background: red;
`;

const TitleHeading = ({title}) => <Heading>{title}</Heading>;

// ...or...

class StatefulTitleHeading extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Heading>{this.props.title}</Heading>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Heading>I'm Heading</Heading>
    <TitleHeading title="I'm TitleHeading"/>
    <StatefulTitleHeading title="I'm StatefulTitleHeading"/>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components@1.4.3/dist/styled-components.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Frankly, though, it makes more sense to just use the component returend by `styled.h1` directly:

```
const Heading = styled.h1`...`;
export default Heading;

// ...then...

<Heading>Children go here</Heading>
```

The semantics of children are already clear, and using `<Heading title="Children go here"/>` instead detracts significantly from that.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I think I just need one more question answered before this all is going to click in my mind.. using styled-components, where would I then define something like the componentDidMount() function?

Comment: Take a look at the StatefulTitleHeading component in my code above. It's just a normal React component and you would define its lifecycle methods just as in any other React component.

Answer (score 4):

Let me make this really simple for you.

Let's create one styled component for heading named 'Heading'

```
const Heading = styled.h1`
  color: 'black';
  font-size: 2rem;
`
```

and now you can use it like following.

```
<Heading>{this.props.title}</Heading>
```

How you manage to get the title prop as it's child is no concern of style component's. It only manages how that title looks. Styled component is not a container that maintains your app/business logic.

Now let's look at an example in it's entirety.

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

// Heading.js (Your styled component)

const Heading = styled.h1`
  color: 'black';
  font-size: 2rem;
`
export default Heading
```

and now your container that will use your styled component

```
// Header.jsx (Your container)
class Header extends Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // This your title that you receive as props
    console.log(nextProps.title)
  }

  render() {
    const { title } = this.props
    return (
      <div id="wrapper">
        <Heading>{title}</Heading>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope that helps. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your answer cleared all my doubts on using styled components.